# How to delete the bootloader

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, multi-boot, bootloader

I dualboot my pc, windows 7 64 bit, and some linux distro, nowadays i'm using crunchbang.

I once had a problem, i lost my bootloader so i created one using [easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). Later on, i installed a linux distro which created its own bootloader.

So when i turn on the computer, the first thing i see is

[image]

That's the bootloader that  crunchbang created, if i don't choose anything, it will boot into crunchbang. If i pick any option however, i will see the second bootloader, which is created by easybcd

[image]

If i don't choose anything here, it will boot into windows 7, if i choose an option, the chosen OS will boot.

I read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/289490/can-i-erase-a-grub-bootloader), won't work for me, since i have 2 bootloaders, tried deleting windows bootloader before, which is so easy using easybcd. I think i have to do the following:

1. Delete crunchbang bootloader, since it is the first bootloader.
2. Use [super grub2 disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to boot windows.
3. Recreate the bootloader using easybcd

I'm not quit sure if that would work, so I'm asking you to see what you think.

By the way, i can't use any solution that requires me to use linux os live cd, live cds don't work on my pc due to [nomodeset](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) problem. I have no windows live cd, but i have created [windows repair cd](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-a-system-repair-disc-in-windows-7/) which works well.

Comment: the second photo you see windows 7, and ubuntu, ubuntu is crunchbang, i forgot to name it crunchbang, i had ubuntu, but now it boots crunchbang and i forgot to name it correctly using easybcd

Comment: Totally unclear what your goal is, which is probably NOT to delete any bootloaders, since then one or more of your OS's will be unbootable. If you just want to omit the second display (from Windows Boot Manager), just use EasyBCD to edit the Windows BCD entries. EasyBCD does NOT create or delete bootloaders, it edits the Windows Boot Manager configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me 4 hours to figure out exactly what to do to fix it, I tried different methods, I deleted and recreated grub many times and repaired windows a billion time, finally here's how I fixed it:

1. Download and burn [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) on a CD or USB
2. Open Easybcd, Click on **BCD backup repair** and do the following: **reset BCD configuration** and **re-create/repair boot files**
3. Click on **BCD deployment**, click **write MBR** and **Install BCD**
4. click on **Add new entry** and Add windows, do not add linux OS
5. Click on **Edit boot menu** and **uncheck** the default checkbox, you do not want windows to be started by default, and check **skip the boot menu**, you do want to skip easybcd's bootloader.
6. Boot **boot-repair-disk** and repair grub, if the automatic repair didn't repair it, click on the **advanced** button and recreate grub, it will tell you the steps, you just need to open **xterm** and follow the commands you see. Once done, you need to use boot-repair-disk again, and now use the automatic solution, it will detect windows.

***Note***

*If you tried to remove everything from easybcd, like if easybcd's boot menu is empty or something, then windows won't boot, you'll have to use windows repair disk to repair windows partition, and when you're done, you're going to see something like **windows 7 (recovered)** boot option, it's better to follow the steps listed above.*

---

I think that just by **spiking easybcd's boot menu**, and **unchecking the default OS checkbox**, you will be able to hide easybcd's boot loader and use linux's bootloader, but i like to follow the steps above just be sure that i have no errors or something.

Comment: Besides when i tried following the second answer, i ended up having having 3 boot loaders instead of 2, much like inception, a grub in a grub in a grub :) so just unchecking the box and skipping the bootloader won't work for me, i mentioned it maybe it works for you.

Comment: And sorry i hate answering my question, but i opened a bounty and no one was interested to i had to do something, i answered it, maybe it helps someone out there

Comment: One last thing, i searched a lot, on how to delete a bootloader and many users, if not all of them say **do not remove the bootloader** I strongly disagree, if you feel like your problem will be solved by removing the bootloader then remove it, just make sure that you have **boot repair disk** or **super grub disk** or something to recreate it and be sure to have windows repair disk in case things go bad, i remove my grub all the time, don't be afraid to do it

Answer (score 0):

The "main" bootloader (the one on sector 0 of your hard drive) seems to be GRUB.  You also have the Windows bootloader likely at the beginning of the Windows partition.

For GRUB to boot Windows it needs to "chain load" the Windows bootloader - it can't boot Windows directly.

If you plan to experiment further with Linux distributions/multiple OSes, I'd suggest you do this:

- Use EasyBCD or `bcdedit.exe` in Windows to remove Ubuntu to from the Windows bootloader - this will prevent that menu from showing up on each boot.
- Change the GRUB configuration and add an Ubuntu boot entry to it.  You can probably clone an existing boot line and simply plug in the partition your Ubuntu install is at.

So this will get you to a point where you don't have two bootloader menus on boot "all over the place."

Your situation is complex with having so many operating systems, so you may need to simply update your bootloaders yourself when something changes and not let external utilities do it.

Things may be easier if you put two disks in your system and use one disk for Windows operating systems and another disk for Linux operating systems.  You can use the boot device menu of your BIOS to select a hard drive to boot from.

Comment: i removed ubuntu from windows bootloader and it still shows, it shows windows option only but still shows, if i remove windows option too i won't be able to boot, tried it before.