# How do I bypass the start up screen in windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7

I have upgraded my os from xp pro to windows 7 ultimate. the only problem I have is at start up screen I get what looks like a dual boot option but one of the options is xp pro setup.
It appears Ive had a failed attempt to install xp at some point. My question is ow do I just bypass the start up screen and go straight to my desktop. 
I've tried EasyBCD but the xp pro setup doesnt show up.
Thank You for any response.

Comment: Would be helpful if you added a screenshot of the start screen your talking about. It is very simple to disable the Start Screen, at least, the one I am thinking of. Windows 7 also supports setting a default user and booting logging into said user account automatically

Comment: please see if my question and my answer help you http://superuser.com/questions/627757/how-to-delete-the-bootloader

Comment: @Fischer Your solution requires a total reinstallation of the MBR and bootsector. This is overkill for such a minor issue and also unnecessary It also bears the risk of the guy screwing up and ending up with an unbootable system.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 I don't believe in "unbootable system" - using  boot repair disk or super grub disk, you can repair anything - booting issue are overrated, if you have the right tools, you can fix it, in the past, every time i screwed my boot menu, i sent it to IT who formatted my pc and told me thats the only way to repair unbooted system - now that i know how silly it is to fix it, i hope the IT guys go to hell, ever since i knew that, I never let an IT man or "mr fix it" touch my phone or PC, i repair everything by myself

Comment: @Fischer When I said "unbootable system" I didn't mean unrepairable. Yes, such errors could be fixed within seconds, but could they also fixed by the very person who can't even find the answer to such a simple question? It's not of much help if he ends up with an unusable boot sector due to an unnecessarily low level change of one of the most vital parts of the system. If he wanted to get rid of the entry then a way less risky solution would be to remove it from the BCD either by using a third party tool or the operating system's bcdedit.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind keeping the old XP entry and just want to skip the screen then you can achieve that by merely setting its display delay to zero. Here's how to do it in Windows:

Go to **Control Panel** --> **System** --> **Advanced**

In the section *Startup and Recovery* click on **Settings**. This will open a window that allows you to set the display interval. Set it to zero. Make sure the drop down list named *Standard operating system* shows your Windows 7 installation and not XP. Click **Okay**. You're done.

You can do the same in EasyBCD:

Click on **Edit Boot Menu**. At the bottom you will find the option **Count down from**. Select it and set it to zero. On the same page there's also a setting called **Skip the boot menu**. This could also do the trick. In any case, make sure that in the above list of operating systems your Windows 7 installation is ticked as default system. Save settings. Done.

Comment: This could be troublesome if their default boot entry is the non-working XP entry . . .

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can`t like that. Tried for 6 hours everything.

https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/

use the nuclear method only one that works

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.